# How to open attached email image through App

Tags: iphone, image

I want to create an app which opens image from email attachment. Here I able to open pdf which is an attachment to my email, I know the setting in info.plist only for open pdf file through my app. Can anyone tell me how to open png or jpg format image through app?
Can anyone tell me setting in info.plist for opening images through app?

Comment: Did the accepted answer solve your problem? I am currently having the same problem: opening PDF documents in my app via "open in..." in Mail works, but opening images that way seems to be either unsupported or to require some kind of special treatment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this answer regarding how to associate file types with an application:
[How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290)